# How to add configurable product to current module?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

Magento 1.9.2.4 using RWD theme.

Could anyone guide me on " How to add configurable products to existing marketplace plugin?" By using plugin I'm able to Create / Upload and manage sellers but it's working only for Simple Products.

I'm looking for a functionality, where Configurable Products also can be added. Could anyone guide me on the same.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Looks like a limitation of this marketplace plugin. It's not possible to help you without knowing the plugin.

Comment: Marketplace here is the link: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace-2.html

Comment: Extension currently not support configurable product, so need to contact extension developers for this, because they provide guide line how you can developed this functionality in extension.